# Obter a soma dos livros dos autores com Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu estou iniciando com o sql e estou tentando obter a soma de todos os livros de cada usuário na tabela carrinho, mas não estou conseguindo.

```
drop table if exists carrinho_de_compras;
drop table if exists usuario;
drop table if exists livro;

create table if not exists livro (
    id_livro bigint not null,
    nome varchar(20) not null,
    preco double not null,
    constraint pk_ID_Livro primary key(id_livro)
);

create table if not exists usuario (
    id_user smallint not null,
    nome varchar(40) not null,
    constraint pk_ID_User primary key(id_user)
);

create table if not exists carrinho_de_compras (
    id_user smallint not null,
    id_livro bigint not null,
    constraint fk_ID_User foreign key(id_user) references usuario(id_user),
    constraint fk_ID_Livro foreign key(id_livro) references livro(id_livro)
);

-- Insere os livros
insert into livro (id_livro, nome, preco) values 
(1, 'Chapeuzinho Vermelho', 4.20), 
(2, 'Os tres Porquinhos', 3.00),
(3, 'Branca de Neve', 3.50);

-- Criaos usuarios
insert into usuario (id_user, nome) 
    values (1, 'Joao da Silva'), (2, 'Pedro Pereira');

-- Adiciona no carrinho de compras
insert into carrinho_de_compras (id_user, id_livro) 
    values (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2);

select usuario.nome, sum(livro.preco) from usuario, livro
    inner join carrinho_de_compras as c on c.id_user = usuario.id_user
    and c.id_livro = livro.id_livro;
```

Ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> 12:31:15  select usuario.nome, sum(livro.preco) from usuario, livro  inner join carrinho_de_compras as c on c.id_user = usuario.id_user     and c.id_livro = livro.id_livro LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'usuario.id_user' in 'on clause'   0.000 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para retornar o preço gasto por cada usuário seria assim

```
SELECT 
usuario.nome, sum(l.preco) as totalGasto
from usuario
-- Juntar todas as compras do usuario
inner join carrinho_de_compras cdp 
    on cdp.id_user = usuario.id_user
-- Pegar a compra do usuario e ver os livros q teve nela
inner join livro l
    on l.id_livro = cdp.id_livro
group by usuario.id_user
```

Agora você irá precisar de fazer uma query separada para retornar os livros comprados por cada usuario

Answer (score 0):

Use a consulta abaixo:

```
select u.nome, sum(l.preco)
from usuario u, livro l, carrinho_de_compras as c 
where c.id_user = u.id_user and c.id_livro = l.id_livro
group by u.nome;
```

Removi o *inner join* e coloquei a validação no *where*; o *mysql* estava "se perdendo" com a validação na cláusula `on`.

Comment: Está retornando só o primeiro usuário. você chegou a testar ?

Comment: @user122974, tem razão, agrupar os resultados resolve o problema. Resposta alterada.

Answer (score 0):

Como que vocÊ quer trazer quantidade de compras somente da tabela carrinho_de_compras voce pode usar o comando.

select id_user,sum(id_livro) as qtd_livros from carrinho_de_compras group by(id_user);

assim ele soma todos id_livro e ordena por usuário com a quantidade do lado.

id_user| qtd_livros
1      |     3
2      |     2

Testa e me fala ai.